# Comparing curves to find anomalies in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, numpy

I am currently working on a Data Mining project in an assembly line. A lot of parts are produced in this assembly line and each part gives me a curve (it's the energy use of the part over the process time -4s)

My aim is it, to compare those curves and see if one of those curves is different to the other curves (anomaly detection). In my test dataset I have 100 curves and 20 of them look significantly different to the "average" curve.

I'm completely new to python and i couldn't find any solution for this problem yet. I have used Sklearn for easier classification problems, but i don't know how to compare whole curves and see if maybe one of them looks differently.

Does anyone now an easy method?
[image: Here my sample data set as a picture]